# Update if exists or create Model in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I got this model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', blank=True, null=True)
    RATING_CONVERSION = (
    (1, '+'),
    (0, '0'),
    (-1, '-'),
    )
    userRating = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RATING_CONVERSION)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.id
```

If post id and user id exists I need to update rating.

I try to make it.
Serializer:

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ExtUser.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True,default=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        field = ('user', 'post')

        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Like.objects.all(),
                fields=('user', 'post')
            )
        ]



    def validate_user(self, value):
        return self.context['request'].user

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Like.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

And ViewSet

```
class LikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['post', 'get'])
    def get_object(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            like = Like.objects.get(user=self.context['request'].user, post = self.context['request'].post)
            if like:
                return like
            else:
                return Like(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        else:
            return super(LikeViewSet, self).get_object()
```

I found a lot of information how to create or update using pk in Url, but I got parameters inside of JSON

This method doesn't work - instead of update rating it creates new Model objects